# The cardinality of the boundary of the support of a continuous function on an interval.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity

Given a continous function $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$, define $\text{supp}(f)=\{x:f(x)\neq0\}$. Can the boundary of this set $\partial \text{supp}(f)$ be uncountable?

I can imagine a continuous function which oscillates rapidly enough to introduce a limit point into the boundary. In fact I can imagine a continuous function with a sequence of points at which the function oscillates infinitely often, introducing a sequence of limit points into the boundary of the support. I believe that I could always my function to introduce a new sequence of limit points into the boundary. However, I can't tell if I could get an uncountable boundary. Is this possible?

Comment: If $C$  is the Cantor middle third set, then $f(x)=d(x,C)$ is continuous and has boundary of its support $C$ hence uncountable.

Comment: Interesting. Can we at least say the boundary of its support has measure 0?

Comment: It need not be. There are variants where the Cantor set has positive measure.

Comment: I see. I'm looking at the Smith–Volterra–Cantor set, which has measure 1/2. Then I can define a continuous function on [0,1] and the set of "places where f goes from positive to 0" has measure 1/2. That is incredibly unintuitive, but such is math.

Comment: I wonder if there is any sensible way to put a restriction on the size of this boundary. I noticed the article on the Cantor set mentioned it is nowhere dense. Perhaps the the boundary of the support is nowhere dense?

Comment: Of course it’s nowhere dense. But that doesn’t limit the measure.